# How to fix a corrupt Delphi 2009 Install

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I installed both the Delphi 2009 trial and actual release via the web installer when I received them and experienced the same errors when installing both.

Both times it appears that the core web installer failed when it went to spawn the additional install packages for boost, documentation and dbtools.  (It brought up a findfile dialog asking for a setup.msi that didn't exist on my machine).  When cancelling out of this, the installer reported a fatal error.

The uninstaller did not appear in my program list, and would did not launch from the installation folder.

Future attempts to bring up the installer had it in a state where it thought Delphi 2009 was already installed and it wouldn't correct or repair or uninstall it.

Comment: Wow! You use Delphi too? I thought I was the only one! :)

Comment: AFAIK, at least for the ISO, the trial and the release are the same - just depending on your serial number.

Comment: The ISO is the same for both.  I'm not sure if you can downgrade a trial install (which is Architect) to the professional install though, which is why I tried uninstalling it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Step 1

Clean out the registry of all things Delphi 2009.

You're looking for *HKLM\Software\Codegear\BDS\6.0* and everything under it. Purge the HKCU equivalent while you're at it.

Search under HKEY.CLASSES.ROOT for anything that contains "CodeGear\RAD Studio\6.0" - assuming you installed into the default folder. Purge all those items from the CLSID level.

### Step 2

Clean up Windows Installer using the [Microsoft Windows Installer Cleanup](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301) utility.

### Step 3

I suggest a reboot at this stage.

### Step 4

Try to install again.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

The problems seem to originate with the web installer not having all the files needed.

Download the 2009 ISO: http://cc.codegear.com/item/26049

Mounted it using this free tool from Microsoft: http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/b/6/7b6abd84-7841-4978-96f5-bd58df02efa2/winxpvirtualcdcontrolpanel_21.exe  (You can burn it to a DVD too)

Then reran the installer.  At this point, both the repair and uninstall worked.

Comment: The ESD and DVD/ISO use the same installer.  The difference is the DVD/ISO has all the packages already locally.